# How can I change location without Wifi

Tags: pokemon-go

I want to play pokemon go, but don't have data on my phone.

Is there any way to change my location on my phone so I can move around without leaving my Wifi?

Comment: No, as far as i know you can't change the location as its based on your current gps. And that's the one moto that you have to go out so sorry, not yet.

Comment: Use public places with wifi hotspots (stations, shopping malls, etc) or get your hands on a device with mobile data and turn that one into a mobile hotspot. Sometimes I carry a 2nd phone around and use its mobile connection with my game phone via wifi.

Comment: @dly Why not post that as an answer?

Comment: @DanmakuGrazer sorry, I was kinda in a hurry and just wanted to respond quickly

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You shouldn't change your location to play this game. You could use GPS-faking apps, however this is bannable according to the terms of use by Niantic, in order to avoid cheating.

I recommend using public wifi hotspots to play the game in this situation, there are parks, malls and shopping centers large enough for a lengthy play, all covered by wifi.

Comment: I wondered if things like that existed, so while waiting for an answer I tried to install one and see. You can change your location, but I think when you are on Wifi it confirms the location via your wifi. So I was seeing my character warp between my real location and my fake one and I couldn't do anything at my fake location. Will accept this one as real answer, as it is a bannable offense to try this. You just have to deal that all pokemon will have to come to you and not you going on an adventure to find them.

Comment: If Niantic discovers that you're spoofing your GPS (which trust me, they'll find out), they can soft ban your in game by making sure no Pokemon ever show up for you for a period of time.

Answer (score 1):

Adding to the accepted answer, Pokemon Go already has "GPS spoofing detection" in play. Using false GPS locations can quickly trigger a 'ban' on Pokemon spawning, much quicker than Niantic might detect on their side.

Even without the risk of an account ban, there is no real advantage to fakitaking your location.

Comment: I see you are new to Arqade. To add to an answer, comment. Only post it as an answer if it brings another solution to the problem. Have fun on the site!

Answer (score 0):

Before I started playing, I had a very similar problem- on my phone plan (TMobile family plan), I have 30MB (Megabytes) of free high-speed data, so I just had my data turned off all the time.

I turned it on specifically for Pokemon Go just to see what happened. It actually took quite a long time (multiple hours) for the game to use up the 30MB, and then I got a push message

> Free T-Mobile Msg: You've exhausted your high speed data limit. Your speed will be reduced until next bill cycle...

I kept playing, and Pokemon Go worked relatively fine on the throttled data.

And then yesterday TMobile announced that at least until August 2017, Pokemon Go data use will not count toward any limit!

So I would check and see if there is a way to get (or if you already have) a cheap data plan that doesn't cut you off, but rather throttles you after you hit the limit. Pokemon Go may still be playable with the very slow data.

Comment: Thats great for you, but doesn't really answer the question